# The maximum size with bytes of one NAL unit

Tags: h.264

I can't find any clue in H.264 spec, anybody can give a clear and simple maximum size regardless of its profile and level?

I'd like to parse H.264 stream, and copy one complete NAL unit buffer to a fixed-size buffer which can hold all bytes of one NAL unit.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AVC level 6.2 allows up to 139264 macro blocks per frame. If we use 10 bit color 4:4:4 it’s 30 bits per pixel. So (30*139264*16*16)/8 gives about 133.7mbytes for an uncompressed image. H.264 has a PCM_I encoding that allows for uncompressed images. There is a little ovehead for the NAL header, so let’s call it 134Mbyte. But in the real world the frame probablly will not be this large, and will likely be compressed.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a maximum for video NALs. In Annex-B format the NALs are start code delimited 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 so there is no limitation through a size field. In MP4 format the size field can have more capacity than most computer's RAM. I'd make a reasonable assumption what buffer size to expect and then reallocate if the maximum is exceeded.